# CASE,LIKE in a EXEC in a dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have requirement to create a stored procedure which will call a exec statement to select a column from a table.I need to have a case and like statement inside it.I can't get the right syntax.I get an error "incorrect syntax near 123".

```
declare @sql varchar(1000)=''
set @sql='exec(''
select 
 case 
    when col like ''123%'' then ''123''
    when col=''234'' then ''234''
    else 'Other' 
 end as col from table'')'
```

Comment: Take your query as-is, do a simple textual replace for `'` to become `''`, then wrap it in a pair of `'`. If you have multiple levels of dynamism, repeat this. And never, ever think about what you're replacing and why, just do it purely mechanically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect the syntax to be like this:

```
declare @sql varchar(1000) = '';
set @sql = ;
select (case when col like ''123%'' then ''123''
             when col  =''234'' then ''234''
             else 'Other' 
        end) as col
from . . .
';

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Your code is referencing `col`, which needs to come from somewhere.  Hence, the `from` clause.

Comment: Got it thanks.Somehow I missed to see that there was an exec inside the sql statement

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this:

```
declare @sql varchar(1000)=''
set @sql= 'select case 
     when col like ''123%'' then ''123''
     when col=''234'' then ''234''
     else ''Other'' 
    end as col
from table'
EXEC (@sql)
```